# JS: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined - define parameters of a class function

Tags: javascript, function, class, sorting

I'm finishing my Twilioquest Javascript Tutorial and one of the final tasks is to build a class with some functions. Every time I run this I get
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined. (at `array.sort();`)

```
class Ducktypium {
    constructor(color) {
        this.color = color;
        if (color != 'red' || 'blue' || 'yellow' ){
            throw error = ("Wrong color!");
        }
    }

    calibrationSequence = [];

    calibrate(input) {
        let array = input;
        let calibrationSorted = array.sort();
        let calibrationMuliplied = calibrationSorted.forEach(item => {
            item * 3;
        });
        return calibrationMuliplied
    }
    calibrationSequence = this.calibrate();
}

var dt = new Ducktypium('red');
dt.calibrate([3, 5, 1]);
console.log(dt.calibrationSequence); // prints [3, 9, 15]
```

The Error is at the calibrate() function of the class. Probably much more errors to it, but I am focusing on the one the console is throwing at me.
I checked similar questions and think that I understand the issue, but their context is different and I just can't get it solved.

As far as I understand `array` does not receive the value I'm trying to pass via `dt.calibrate([3, 5, 15]);` so the `.sort()` function doesn't apply to anything. But the code looks similar to other attempts at doing something like this so I just can't find the problem.

Comment: You have this in your class `calibrationSequence = this.calibrate();` which makes `input` undefined; just remove that line. Also other small errors. Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/red29fx7/

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you very much! I have updated my code and it works leaving me with more questions than before though. 
Why does using .map make more sense than .forEach here? And is what is the difference between && and || ?

Comment: && is the AND operator; you had ||, which means OR.  You have to state each condition in full, and to test whether `color` is different from all three, you have to combine the tests with `&&` (because any random color is different to at least two out of three values, so your condition would've always been true)

Comment: Regarding forEach vs. map: the former iterates over the array (and returns nothing), the latter turns the array into a new array which consists of the elements returned by the function (you also didn't return anything).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code with detailed explanations

```
class Ducktypium {
    constructor(color) {
        this.color = color;
         // && means AND while || means OR
         // You have to be specific with your conditions and the if statement
         // only runs when the condition provided is met
        if (color != 'red' && color != 'blue' && color != 'yellow' ) {
            throw Error("Wrong color!");  // You throw an Error object
        }
    }

    // calibrationSequence = [];

    calibrate(input) {
        let array = input;
        let calibrationSorted = array.sort();
        // This line is wrong. forEach loops through the items in your array and pass that item into a function but doesn't return anything
        // let calibrationMuliplied = calibrationSorted.forEach(item => {
        //     item * 3;
        // });

        // What you intended was the map() function
        // map() calls the function you provide on each item and modifies them in the array
        let calibrationMultiplied = calibrationSorted.map((item) => {
            return item * 3
        });

        // The difference between forEach and map is that
        // Lets say you have a box of numbered balls
        // in forEach you take out each ball and note the number multiplied by two and put the
        // ball back
        // in map you take out each ball and actually rewrite the number as its number multiplied
        // by two and put it back in
        
        return calibrationMultiplied
    }
    // You are calling the calibrate method without passing anything into "input"
    // that's why sort() is called on nothing and you get an error
    // calibrationSequence = this.calibrate();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have wrong statement of "`calibrationSequence = this.calibrate()`", please make it like bellow code and also "`if (color != 'red' || 'blue' || 'yellow' )`" this should have and condition `(this.color !== 'red' && this.color !== 'blue' && this.color !== 'yellow' )`

```
calibrationSequence = [];

calibrate(input) {
  let array = input;
  let calibrationSorted = array.sort();
  let calibrationMuliplied = calibrationSorted.forEach(item => {
    item * 3;
  });
  return calibrationMuliplied
}
calibrationSequence = this.calibrate;
}
```